# If-else statement in R to describe three different cases

Tags: r, if-statement

What is an efficient way to describe three different cases for `x<y`, `x>y` and `x=y`? Here `x` and `y` are two numbers. I thought the following:

```
if (x<y) {
  ...
}
if (x>y) {
  ...
}
if (x=y) {
  ...
}
```

Maybe I could use `ifelse` statement?

Comment: you can have a look at `?dplyr::case_when` but mostly it depends on your use-case. A specific example would have been helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The else-if construction should be on the same line as the last brace of the preceding block.
 The **ifelse** function is probably not what you're looking for if you're looking to execute multiple statements.

```
if (x<y) {
  ...
} else if (x>y) {
  ...
} else if (x=y) {
  ...
}
```